# Objective-C: Edit contents of plist in app bundle

Tags: objective-c, installation

I have an installer which places an app inside `/Applications`. After the app is copied there, I wrote an installer plugin to get user configurations such as server address and port number. The plugin writes these configs to a plist file inside /Applications/myapp.app.

I'm writing:

```
NSString *filePath = @"/Applications/emptyapp.app/Contents/Resources/DummyConfig.plist";
NSString *test = @"somestring";
NSError *error;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
[test writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if(error){
    [self alert:error.localizedDescription];
}
```

Im getting permission denied for writing there, which makes sense, but how do I get around this?

These configs are a one time setup and should only be accessed by admins, not regular users.

(I am using [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) to make the installer, and building the plugin in Objective C. Packages does have a checkbox 'require admin password', but it doesnt seem to use those credentials for anything since i cant write to the app bundle.)

Comment: I don't think you should write to the App Bundle. If Apple allowed that, then other apps easily hack and change things in other apps. What you need to do is write to Documents folder of the app.

Comment: Ok, I've come up with a work around with temp files. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice he would be to have your app write and access that plist file inside the user's Library folder somewhere, typically in Application Support. Then you wouldn't need to worry about permissions issues or the system possibly detecting your app as being corrupted. If you absolutely need to modify something in your app package, the installer would need to run all the way through with elevated permissions, or you will need to build a mechanism for gaining elevated permissions into your app (eg Little Snitch)